# estimate time delay between event timestamps

Tags: algorithm, timedelay, digital-logic

I have two devices (in this case, computers), each with a local clock and ability to timestamp digital events, i.e. they can detect and timestamp input digital transitions, and produce and timestamp output digital events. My goal is to find the offset between the clocks of the two devices.

I have two physical mechanisms to do this synchronizaton: I am sending a digital pulse at random (but accurately timestamped) intervals from one device to the other, and I have an external source that is sending pulses which are being recorded and timestamped at both devices. There is a possibility that one device starts recording earlier, or even skips some events.

Example:

Recorded timestamps

Device 1: **0,100,125,200,275,300**

Device 2: **1000,1025,1100,1175,1200,1450**

The time delay in this case is **900** (events 2,3,4,5,6 on device 1 corresponds to events 1,2,3,4,5 on device 2)

I've been looking at solutions using cross-correlation (works best for continuous, or at least uniformly sampled discrete signals), and other more complex distributed computing solutions (NTP for e.g.). I have a feeling that there should be an algorithmically simple and elegant way of achieving this.

Thank you in advance to any responders!

Comment: Your first mechanism seems to be better just for the reason that you have errors only on one device. The generating one has exact timestamps and does not loose events. But the actual selection of the mechanism also depends on, whether the approximate frequency is the same for both mechanisms and whether there could be a too long gap for the first mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can normalize your two signals and then perform a sequence alignment.  There are many algorithms for this, people in bioinformatics use similar approaches regularly.  The most common are based on dynamic programming algorithms, though some do use cross correlation (e.g. MAFFT).  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact use-case [Nearest-Advocate](https://github.com/iot-salzburg/nearest-advocate) is developed for:
It matches each event in the test array (second) with the nearest advocate event in the reference array (first one). The mean distance of all matches is used as a metric for time synchronicity.

```
pip install nearest_advocate
```

```py
import numpy as np
import nearest_advocate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr_ref = np.array([0,100,125,200,275,300])
arr_sig = np.array([1000,1025,1100,1175,1200,1450])

time_shifts = nearest_advocate.nearest_advocate(arr_ref=arr_ref, arr_sig=arr_sig,
td_min=-1500, td_max=1500, sps=1)
time_shift, min_mean_dist = time_shifts[np.argmin(time_shifts[:,1])]
print(f"Found an optimum at {time_shift:.4f}s with a minimal mean distance of {min_mean_dist:.6f}s")

plt.plot(time_shifts[:,0], time_shifts[:,1], color="steelblue", label="Mean distance")
plt.vlines(x=time_shift, ymin=min_mean_dist, ymax=np.mean(time_shifts[:,1]), color="firebrick", label=f"Shift = {time_shift:.2f}s")
plt.hlines(y=np.mean(time_shifts[:,1]), xmin=-60, xmax=60, color="black", label="Mean distance")

plt.xlim(time_shift-200, time_shift+200)
plt.title("Characteristic Curve of Nearest Advocate")
plt.xlabel("Time offset (s)")
plt.ylabel("Mean distance (s)")
plt.show()
```

A time delay of 900 (s?) for device 2 was estimated.

[image: Characteristic Curve]

Disclaimer: I had similar problems and developed and validated this method.